# what is meant by unrelated classes?

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class, abstract

While studying abstract classes and interfaces 
I get the statement 
 " You expect that unrelated classes would implement your interface. For example, the interfaces Comparable and Cloneable are implemented by many unrelated classes. "

I don't know what is meant by unrelated classes here.

Comment: Unrelated: having nothing [else] in common. (This usually implies that they are not related to each other by inheritance; and the only base type they have in common is Object.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at some examples from the standard Java API:

The interface [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is implemented by many classes, like `File` and `Integer`, which are unrelated to each other. There's a whole list of classes which implement `Comparable` in the link above. That's fine, because `Comparable` defines only a single method (`compareTo`) which every class implements on its own way, without some shared code which could be beneficial to every `Comparable` class.

On the other hand, two classes extending a single abstract class like [`Format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) are usually closely related, like [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). The abstract class allows for the definition of some convenience/utility methods which are useful for every subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Both abstract classes and interfaces serve to share some functionality.

Classes can be related by inheritance, for example every `Button` is also a `Control` and as such has `Control`'s methods, properties etc (everything that a `Control` has plus its own members).

Interfaces are a way to share some functionality between classes not related by inheritance, for example both `String` and `DateTime` implement `IComparable`, so both have `CompareTo` method and you can say both are instances of `IComparable`.

Answer (score 0):

Like **user2864740** already commented

> Unrelated: having nothing [else] in common

For example a Lamborghini is unrelated to a Pitbull, but a Lamborghini is related to car.
Because a Lamborghini is obvios a car. 
So it has all features each car has. 
Now the Pitbull has no features a car has ergo he is unrelated to car.